# Intellij IDEA "Smart Indent", remove tab after method declaration

Tags: java, coding-style, intellij-idea, formatting

I have to comply with a coding standard for school and it requires me to put my brackets on their own separate line. This is fine, I figured this out.

If I type the following Java code and then hit enter after '()':

```
Element peek()
    //cursor is placed here
//but I want it to end up here, one line up
```

This requires me to hit back four times every time I declare a new method and hit enter for my opening bracket.

I can disable Smart Indent but then it wouldn't indent for me once I actually do declare brackets. I can reduce the intent value down to zero but then I can't tab.

I just want it to not "Smart Indent" after a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you hit enter following the method's parentheses, just type the opening brace. IDEA will automatically place it where it needs to be via smart indent. Then hit enter to get to the next line and IDEA will indent that next line, as well as put in the closing brace (assuming you have *Editor > Smart Keys > Insert Pair bracket* or *Editor > Smart Keys > Enter > Insert pair '}'* enabled).

So if you type:

Element<kbd>Space</kbd>peek()<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>{</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

You'll end up with:

```
Element peek()
{
    |
}
```

Where | is the cursor.

Showing that Step by Step:

1) Element<kbd>Space</kbd>peek()

```
Element peek()|
```

2) <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
Element peek()
    |
```

3) <kbd>{</kbd>

```
Element peek()
{|}
```

4) <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
Element peek()
{
    |
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to type that out. It did work exactly as you said it would, I'm not sure why it wasn't doing this before but whatever, since it's working now. Thank you!